# What does "drop an appeal" mean?

Tags: meaning

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/FJxUN-kNXNs). It is at 6 minute and 13 second.

> Twelve years later, 2006, I learned that the man **dropped all of his appeals**, and his execution date was approaching.

Does the speaker mean that all of the man's attempts to get acquitted failed, or that he accepted the sentence?

Comment: You can drop any kind of legal case. This means you do not continue with it. E.g. *The prosecution dropped the case against the accused owing to a lack of evidence.*

Answer (score 2):

It means he accepted the sentence. To "drop an appeal" is to withdraw the attempt for retrial.